# Creating password using Python passlib

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the following that another user posted as an answer to a different question:

```
>>> # import the hash algorithm
>>> from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

>>> # generate new salt, and hash a password
>>> hash = sha256_crypt.encrypt("toomanysecrets")
>>> hash
```

But when I type `from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
<module> ImportError: No module named passlib.hash
>>>
```

I have already done `pip install passlib`. Any ideas?

Result of running: `pip install passlib`:

```
Downloading/unpacking passlib   Downloading passlib-1.6.2.tar.gz (408kB): 408kB downloaded   Running setup.py egg_info for package passlib

Installing collected packages: passlib   Running setup.py install for passlib
    error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/passlib': Permission denied
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/var/folders/2t/1yj5qss57xz8sb7p9wymtkdr0000gn/T/pip_build_<user>/passlib/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/2t/1yj5qss57xz8sb7p9wymtkdr0000gn/T/pip-epiHNK-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib

creating build/lib/passlib

copying passlib/__init__.py -> build/lib/passlib

copying passlib/apache.py -> build/lib/passlib

copying passlib/apps.py -> build/lib/passlib

copying passlib/context.py -> build/lib/passlib

copying passlib/exc.py -> build/lib/passlib

copying passlib/hash.py -> build/lib/passlib

copying passlib/hosts.py -> build/lib/passlib

copying passlib/ifc.py -> build/lib/passlib

copying passlib/registry.py -> build/lib/passlib

copying passlib/win32.py -> build/lib/passlib

creating build/lib/passlib/ext

copying passlib/ext/__init__.py -> build/lib/passlib/ext

creating build/lib/passlib/ext/django

copying passlib/ext/django/__init__.py -> build/lib/passlib/ext/django

copying passlib/ext/django/models.py -> build/lib/passlib/ext/django

copying passlib/ext/django/utils.py -> build/lib/passlib/ext/django

creating build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/__init__.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/bcrypt.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/cisco.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/des_crypt.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/digests.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/django.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/fshp.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/ldap_digests.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/md5_crypt.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/misc.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/mssql.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/mysql.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/oracle.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/pbkdf2.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/phpass.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/postgres.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/roundup.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/scram.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/sha1_crypt.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/sha2_crypt.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/sun_md5_crypt.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

copying passlib/handlers/windows.py -> build/lib/passlib/handlers

creating build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/__main__.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/_test_bad_register.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/backports.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/test_apache.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/test_apps.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/test_context.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/test_context_deprecated.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/test_ext_django.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/test_handlers.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/test_handlers_bcrypt.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/test_handlers_django.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/test_hosts.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/test_registry.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/test_utils.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/test_utils_crypto.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/test_utils_handlers.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/test_win32.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/tox_support.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/utils.py -> build/lib/passlib/tests

creating build/lib/passlib/utils

copying passlib/utils/__init__.py -> build/lib/passlib/utils

copying passlib/utils/compat.py -> build/lib/passlib/utils

copying passlib/utils/des.py -> build/lib/passlib/utils

copying passlib/utils/handlers.py -> build/lib/passlib/utils

copying passlib/utils/md4.py -> build/lib/passlib/utils

copying passlib/utils/pbkdf2.py -> build/lib/passlib/utils

creating build/lib/passlib/utils/_blowfish

copying passlib/utils/_blowfish/__init__.py -> build/lib/passlib/utils/_blowfish

copying passlib/utils/_blowfish/_gen_files.py -> build/lib/passlib/utils/_blowfish

copying passlib/utils/_blowfish/base.py -> build/lib/passlib/utils/_blowfish

copying passlib/utils/_blowfish/unrolled.py -> build/lib/passlib/utils/_blowfish

creating build/lib/passlib/_setup

copying passlib/_setup/__init__.py -> build/lib/passlib/_setup

copying passlib/_setup/docdist.py -> build/lib/passlib/_setup

copying passlib/_setup/stamp.py -> build/lib/passlib/_setup

copying passlib/tests/sample1.cfg -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/sample1b.cfg -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/sample1c.cfg -> build/lib/passlib/tests

copying passlib/tests/sample_config_1s.cfg -> build/lib/passlib/tests

running install_lib

creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/passlib

error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/passlib': Permission denied

---------------------------------------- Cleaning up... Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/var/folders/2t/1yj5qss57xz8sb7p9wymtkdr0000gn/T/pip_build_<user>/passlib/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/2t/1yj5qss57xz8sb7p9wymtkdr0000gn/T/pip-epiHNK-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/2t/1yj5qss57xz8sb7p9wymtkdr0000gn/T/pip_build_<user>/passlib Storing complete log in /Users/<user>/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Comment: Find ```passlib``` in your site packages and confirm that it has ```sha256_crypt``` in it

Comment: @wnnmaw - It's not even finding `passlib.hash`.

Comment: @rctneil - What OS and Python version are you on?

Comment: @Drewness, errr, right, yeah, that's what I meant.  Check to see if what it claims isn't there is actually there

Comment: I'm using OSX 10.9 and python 2.7.5. I guess that's the version that came bundled with OSX.

Comment: @rctneil - and are you running it from bash or an IDE..?

Comment: Does `import passlib` work? If so does `import passlib.hash`?

Comment: @cmd Neither `import passlib` or `import passlib.hash` work. @Drewness Running direct from an iTerm terminal window.

Comment: @rctneil, try ```pip freeze``` and see if ```passlib``` shows up

Comment: @rctneil - what if you save the script as a `.py` and run it from the terminal. Same thing?

Comment: @wnnmaw No sign of passlib

Comment: @rctneil Well there's your problem.  Can you post the output of ```pip install passlib```?

Comment: `passlib` is not installed correctly

Comment: @wnnmaw  Added result in OP. Noticed theres an error. I'm not up on Python, any ideas on how I can solve it?

Comment: Working now. needed sudoing. Thanks all!

Comment: BTW, I tried running the version of the script in password.py by running `python password.py` and it ran but gave no output to the terminal, how can I get it to do that?

Comment: Whenever you try to add another hashing function i.e., `pip install bcrypt`, it overrides passlib modules that causes `hash` function and others to be not defined. If you try to `dir(passlib)` after you have imported it you find it only has dunder methods. That happened even when I used different environments (conda ones). 
I solved it by reinstalling passlib again `pip install -U passlib` which in most cases uses a cache version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing passlib was denied so needed `sudo`'ing by running:

`sudo pip install passlib`

Credit to @Drewness, @wnnmaw and @cmd

Answer (score 12):

You’re getting a ‘permission denied’ error.  Try

```
sudo pip install passlib
```

or

```
pip install --user passlib
```

Comment: This is the correct answer but i'm hesitant to accept it as other people helped me in the comments thread above. To keep things fair, i'm going to answer the question myself and accept that one giving credit to those above. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can now use the very slick:

```
sqlalchemy_utils.types.password.PasswordType
```

Then SQLAlchemy will do the encoding/decoding for you. For example:

```
class User(Base):
    password = Column(PasswordType())
```

and then setting and getting is pretty standard python code and all the real action happens behind the scenes:

```
user = User()

# set password
user.password = 'foo'   # '$5$rounds=80000$H.............'

# check password
user.password == 'foo'  # true
```